# dbus signal for volume up & down

Tags: ubuntu, dbus, maverick

I recently upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat and to my dismay, the mediakeys "volume up" and "volume down" do not send **Dbus signals** anymore... how can I add these back?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the root cause of this problem is the service **HAL**: somehow, this service isn't started most of the time on my machine.  To start, use:

`sudo hald --daemon=yes`

Answer (score 0):

To configure the keys used for volume up, and volume down, press ALT+F2, type in `gconf-editor`, and press Enter.  Then, navigate to `/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/keybindings`.

The values on my system are:
`volume_down` -> `XF86LowerVolume`
`volume_up` -> `XF86RaiseVolume`
`volume_mute` -> `XF86Mute`

If those don't work for you you can use `xev` to figure out the exact keycode your media keys fire and configure those.

Comment: the problem isn't the keycodes nor the functionality associated with the keys per-se but the **lack dbus** signals generated as a result of pressing those media keys.

Comment: If *gnome-settings-daemon* is picking up on the keypresses but not firing the dbus signals then there is a bug in that package.  You can report it to Ubuntu with specific information about your system by running `apport-bug gnome-settings-daemon`.

Comment: thanks for the pointer.  I have filed a bug report:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/740988